# How can I change ports on an Docker container?

Tags: networking, docker

I created a docker container with also the command part `-p :8080` so
a random port from the host will route the requests to the port 8080 on the docker container --> `0.0.0.0:49153->8080/tcp`
 I had to write `-p 8080:8080` so the request to the port 8080 on the host will route this requests to the 8080 port on the docker container.

How can I change this that the port 8080 of the host will connect to the port 8080 of the docker container?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080` and that would connect the container port to the host port which both happen to be the same number. I personally prefer having the IP address there as well, just for self-documenting the code.

Comment: `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080` has different effect than `-p 8080:8080`, and other than `-p 8080`. First opens port at `127.0.0.1:8080`, second opens `0.0.0.0:8080`, and third opens `0.0.0.0:<random 49152 to 65535 port>`, (all three mapped to 8080 port of container indeed).